# CPU frequency scaling issue - scaling_max_freq wrong

Tags: cpufreq, frequency, scaling

I have the an issue on my Elitebook Core 2 Duo T9600, the scaling stops to work after few seconds of high load and get stuck at **800Mhz**.

Temperature is around 50-60°C for both cores, **bios_limit** is reporting the correct max speed **2534000 (2.53Ghz)**. The only wrong information I can find is in */sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq* which shows **1520400** rather than **2534000** but anyway, the CPU never goes beyond 800Mhz.
It appears either on AC and on battery.

My system: Ubuntu Raring 13.04 Kernel 3.8.0-19-generic x86-64

Is there a way to disable completely the scaling. I don't have any cpu freq manager running in userland.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/303882/maximum-cpu-frequency-stuck-at-low-value

Answer (score 3):

OK, after few days of work, I think I can say this issue **is solved** ->
Use governor **conservative** and reset the **scaling_max_freq** as follow (if it changed):

*(to do for each core)*

```
echo conservative > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  
echo 2530000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

The issue comes from the governor **ondemand**. After few seconds in high loads, it, somehow, reset the value of **scaling_max_freq** to 1520400 which become read-only or at least, can't be modified under "ondemand" governance and the CPU get stuck at the lowest frequency. I can reproduce the behavior.

Unfortunately, cpufreq-utils can't help (eg:`/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils`) and I can't set these values at boot time (eg: `/etc/rc.local` 0555'd), I have to apply it through a script with a cron job.

Where should I inform of this bug?

Comment: I am getting the same issue now on Ubuntu 14.10. Getting hopping mad at this.

Comment: I don't even have that governor as an option...