# How to change "scaling_max_freq" file (set max frequency higher)?

Tags: scaling, frequency

I have AMD A6-7310 which supports boost clock of 2.4 GHz. But, in Ubuntu 18.04, it only goes to 2.0 GHz.

If I go to: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_max_freq
and open that file, it shows "2000000" (2 GHz).
I want to change that (on all 4 cores/files) to "2400000" (2.4 GHz), but I can not save the changes.

How can I do this? How can I change this file?

I still want to have automatic scalling, as it is now, but to go to the max supported frequency.

I have also tried this: [Set CPU governor to performance in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021748/set-cpu-governor-to-performance-in-18-04)
But no changes.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/303957/15811 should do it. Mind the "#" You need root for this (and not sudo)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried installing Nautilus Admin Tool, and changing those files. But eve after that, it still goes up to 2 GHz. There is also file "bios_limit" (/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0), that is set to 2 GHz, and even with "edit as administrator" I cannot save the changes. Also, I don not know how to run termial as root. :/

Comment: What if I delete /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/bios_limit file?

Comment: I have, using ALT+F2, pasted and entered these commands: "echo 1 > /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc", "echo -n 2410000 >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq" and "cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq2410000". Now, cores go up to 2.325 GHz (max recorded so far). BUT, under load (video encoding, all 4 cores at 100%) it goes up to 2 GHz, sometimes close to 2.1 GHz. And it is is not after it heats up, but as soon as I load the CPU. ALSO, with almost no load, cores no longer go down to 800 MHz or so, but stay at around 2 GHz, which is not good. :/

Answer (score 1):

From: http://laptopmedia.com/processor/amd-a6-7310/

> AMD A6-7310 is a 4 core, entry-level processor announced in Q2 of
>   2015. It is part of AMD’s “Carrizo-L” architecture family and operates at a base frequency of 2.0GHz. If a higher frequency is needed, its
>   cores can overclock to 2.4 GHz thanks to the TurboCore functionality.

I don't have an AMD CPU to give exact instructions, but you need to enable **TurboCore** just like **TurboBoost** needs to be enabled for Intel platforms:

```
echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

- This enables turbo boost.

and

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

- This disables turbo boost.

Further reading:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/boost.txt
- [AMD Turbo boost doesn't work for A8-7600 Desktop CPU](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211368)

---

From [How to set up a Debian system (focus on 2D or console/server) with an AMD Turbo Core APU for maximum energy and computing efficiency?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241825/how-to-set-up-a-debian-system-focus-on-2d-or-console-server-with-an-amd-turbo), you need to install Radeon driver. Most likely you need to append `radeon.bapm=1` to the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`

:

Comment: Thank you. But I have still not managed to find solution.

Comment: I'll research it more in depth tonight. I recall reading about a kernel parameter but was not sure if it works for your processor.

Comment: Hey man, you don't need t do that. I am not asking anyone to do reaserch for me. I was just hopping that someone knows how to fx this, and can tell me in a few minutes. But thank you for your help anyway. I have submited a ticket to AMD. Maybe they can help me. No way of contacting HP, of course...

Comment: @ПротивГлобал I added a bottom section with the kernel parameter. You should read the entire link for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Mesa drivers. So, I am not sure what would happen if I run those commands. I still want to continue to use Mesa. I am sorry, I have poor understanding of software. :/

Comment: I have tried contactind AMD support, got a useless answer. Asked for help on HP forum, they said they don't give support to Linux. What if I delete  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/bios_limit file?

Comment: I have, using ALT+F2, pasted and entered these commands: "echo 1 > /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc", "echo -n 2410000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq" and "cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq2410000". Now, cores go up to 2.325 GHz (max recorded so far). BUT, under load (video encoding, all 4 cores at 100%) it goes up to 2 GHz, sometimes close to 2.1 GHz. And it is is not after it heats up, but as soon as I load the CPU. ALSO, with almost no load, cores no longer go down to 800 MHz or so, but stay at around 2 GHz, which is not good. :/